# Search in Excel loops to infinity, why?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with two data columns. I need to find the line where both of them are a hit. So far this is what my code looks like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Set rgfound = ws.Range("A:A").Find(MyInputOne.value), LookAt:=xlWhole)
If rgfound Is Nothing Then 
    MsgBox "No results"
    Exit Sub
Else
    If rgfound.Offset(0, 3).Value <> MyInputTwo.Value Then
        Do
            Set rgfound = ws.Range("A:A").FindNext(rgfound)
        Loop Until rgfound.Offset(0, 3).Value = MyInputTwo.Value
    End If
End If
rgfound.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Found!"
```

This enters an infinite loop and crashes, and I have to force quit excel after running it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use loops for this kind of thing.

The built in `AutoFilter` is super quick if you know how to manipulate it in VBA and it will avoid any need for loops/ problems with infinite loops

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindBoth()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim data As Range, result As Range

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set data = sht.Range("A1:D101")

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False 'clear existing filter

    With data
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=8
        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="A"
        Set result = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1)
        If Not Intersect(result, data) Is Nothing Then
            result.Offset(0, 5).Resize(1, 1).Value = "Found!"
        End If
    End With

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

My data looked like this:

[image]

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! The only trouble I had was that sht.AutoFilterMode =False did not reset the filters. However, since my data were part of a table I could use Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter instead for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it loops to infinity, because the code never satisfies this condition:

```
Loop Until rgfound.Offset(0, 3).Value = MyInputTwo.Value
```

To see what is happening write:

```
Debug.Print rgfound.Offset(0, 3).Value 
Debug.Print MyInputTwo.Value
```

before the condition above. Another option to check what is happening is to introduce some counter, which would force the code to stop after the 2000. iteration. Like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt As Long
    Do
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Debug.Assert cnt < 2000
        Debug.Print cnt
    Loop Until False

End Sub
```

Once it stops because of the fail of the `Debug.Assert` condition, you would be able to debug manually and to get what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the most simplistic answer here, but if you know your parameters and it should never 'Loop' over a certain amount of times, you can try putting a `FOR I` / `NEXT I` statement.

Just another idea to throw out there.